# PHP mail() configuration issue

Tags: php, yii

Mails are sending from my php application using `mail` function. But client says it is from `Mandril` mail service. I logged into the Mandril account and found the mails sent. I checked the code. But didn't see any piece of code using the Mandril mail. It only uses php mail function. How can verify this?

My send mail path is configured like:

sendmail_path is `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fadmin@abc.com -Fno-reply.`

**Note**: *I don't have access to the server.*

Comment: You should switch to using the best email client ever made for PHP: http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Mandril` mail account was configured in `sendmail` confuguration. So when ever we use the php `mail()` function it will send through this account. Since the configuration lies in the `send mail` config file no any piece of code was there in the php code.